# prime distribution lower bound: Does the inequality hold for $s=19/10$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Define a transformation of the prime counting function, $\pi(k)$, by  $$J:  (0,1) \longrightarrow  (0,1) $$

where

$$J(x)= \lim_{r \to \infty} \frac{\int_2^{rx} \pi(k) \, dk }{\int_2^r \pi(k) \, dk}$$

I'm interested in optimizing the following over $s,t \in \Bbb R_+$

$$ x^s\le J(x) \le x^t $$

Let $t=1.$

> Does the inequality hold for $s=19/10$?

Comment: @mathworker21 It is for $x\in(0,1)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It follows from the prime number theorem that
$$\int_2^r \pi(k) \, dk\sim\frac{r^2}{2\log r},\qquad r\to\infty,$$
hence also that
$$J(x)=x^2,\qquad x>0.$$

Comment: @53Demonslayer No, this is a literal equality. From the asymptotic GH mentions, you get $\frac{\int_2^{rx} \pi(k) \, dk }{\int_2^r \pi(k) \, dk}\sim \frac{(rx)^2/\log(rx)}{r^2/\log x}=x^2\frac{\log(rx)}{\log r}$, and for any $x$ the limit of this as $r\to\infty$ is exactly $x^2$.

Comment: @Wojowu okay I gotcha. I just calculated it and found that which is why i deleted my comment

Comment: @53Demonslayer Wojowu had some typos. The corrected formula reads $\frac{\int_2^{rx} \pi(k) \, dk }{\int_2^r \pi(k) \, dk}\sim \frac{(rx)^2/\log(rx)}{r^2/\log r}=x^2\frac{\log(r)}{\log(rx)}\sim x^2$.

Comment: @GHfromMO I like your answer, but Im surprised because I specifically asked about bounds especially if $s=19/10$ holds

Comment: @53Demonslayer The point is that $J(x)$ is precisely $x^2$. In particular, $J(x)<x^{19/10}$ for any $x\in(0,1)$.

Comment: @GHfromMO I accepted your answer. Would you say that $J(x)$ encodes $\pi(k)$ or that information is lost In the transformation?

Comment: @53Demonslayer $J(x)=x^2$ is due to the fact that $\pi(k)$ is very regular asymptotically. Indeed, $\pi(k)\sim k/\log k$.